# why urls appending to ieframe?

Tags: dll, internet-explorer-8, proxy, dns, ieframe.dll

i am trying to hit the url from my local browser "https://MySite"
I can see always ieframe appending and url formatted as like below **res://ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff_webOC.htm#https://Mysite**

What could be reason?

Please help me